# Open automatically .ics on Android

Tags: php, android, windows-phone, icalendar

On my website I have a button, and when I click on this button, I download a file called "event.ics". On Iphone, when the file is downloaded, he is automatically read and I can choose my calendar, but on Android and Windows Phone, I need to click on file downloaded or to go in folder "download" to execute the `.ics`. Is there a way to read/execute the `.ics` on Android and WP automatically ?

Here you can see my code to download the calendar file :

```
public function createEventCalendar($start, $end, $description, $location)
{
    $event = array();
    $rand = rand(5, 1000000000);

    $event['name'] = "event";
    $event['data'] = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nPRODID:-//TEST//TEST//EN\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTAMP:".date('Ymd\THis')."\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nUID:".$rand."\r\nDTSTART:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($start))."\r\nDTEND:".date('Ymd\THis', strtotime($end))."\r\nSUMMARY:Blablabla\r\nDESCRIPTION:".$description."\r\nLOCATION:".$location."\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR";

    return $event;
}

public function downloadEventCalendar($event)
{
    $eventname = $event['name'].'.ics';

    header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$eventname."\"");

    echo $event['data'];
    exit();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Up, That is not possible to execute `.ics`on Android automatically when the file is downloaded ?